# MongoDB pagination Issue using limit and skip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

This is my code. msisdn field is unique for user collection.I want to get records batchwise.But same records are fetched multiple times

```
count = user_ids.count
current_limit =0
while count >0
    users.where(:id.in=> user_ids).skip(current_limit*100).limit(100).each do |user|
       file.write("#{user.msisdn}\n")
    end
    count-=100
    current_limit+=1
    end
end
```

Comment: You may want to order by something before skipping, otherwise I don't know of any guarantee that elements will remain in the same order when you query the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.sort is not consistent.So whenever you are using pagination we must use sort.I reached to this conclusion from #mongodbengine channel on freenode. Ideally mongodb skip must be avoided because this is expensive.Check document. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/